# Equivalent circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source

Can I simplify this circuit to just one resistor? How can I find the equivalent voltage of the current source in this circuit?

[image: schematic]

Comment: Using an image link as a title is unacceptable. Use proper descriptive title related to the content of your post.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: Have you counted the number of nodes in the existing circuit?

Comment: Hint: R3 is shorted out so does nothing useful, remove it now what can you tell me about R1 and R2?  Can they be simplified?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way:

Identify and remove shorted resistor. Simplify remaining resistors.

---

Hard way:

Use a delta-y transform to convert the three resistors to the y-topology. In the y-topology, two of the three resistors you have will then be in parallel. Since they're in parallel, simplify them to one resistor. Now you'll have two resistors in series. Add them together and you'll have one equivalent resistance and one current source which will give you a voltage.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform

Comment: Did you miss the funny way R3 is connected?

Comment: Hah, good call. I like doing things the hard way apparently.

Answer (score 0):

redraw this circuit as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhn3jA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can ignore resistance R3 from the circuit since there is a parallel non resistance path across it. Circuit is then simplified in to R1 // R2. That is 50 ohm resistance in parallel with 1A current source. Circuit is equivalent to 50V( 1A * 50ohm) with a series 50 Ohm resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ0aUC.png)</sup>